# What is MetaMask's security model?

Tags: metamask, security

Does it download block headers, like a Bitcoin SPV wallet? Or does it rely on a service like Infura to provide an API that it trusts to tell it what it holds? If the latter, could the service lie about the contents of the wallet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that it relies on the RPC API you provide it. The RPC can lie as you say but you can always just change the RPC (though you can't change the RPC for Ethereum mainnets or testnets).

The reason why I find this to be likely is due to the fact of when the RPC you have listed goes down, your Metamask wallet is inaccessible and it's assets don't update. Also this warning comes up when you add a network:
[image: API network provider warnings]

You can find what RPC Metamask is using for each network you have on it in Metamask's **Settings** section under **Networks**:
[image: Example Metamask networks]